# Bounding Product of Nonnegative Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}_{\geq0}$, not necessarily square, have nonnegative elements, and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^m_{\geq 0}$ be nonnegative. Clearly $Ax$ is a nonnegative vector. Suppose in addition that $\|Ax\|_{\infty} < 1$, that is, each component of the product $Ax$ is less than one.

Can one derive a nice upper bound on $\|x\|_{\infty}$? The specific case of $A$ row-stochastic is also of interest to me, and may simplify things.

The most useful idea I've found in this direction is that of "A Matrix Lower Bound" by Grcar, but the results are not quite as clean as I would like.

Comment: Some bounds off the top of my head are $\|Ax\|_{\infty} \leq \|Ax\|_{2}$ and $\|Ax\|_{2} \leq \sqrt{\|Ax\|_{1}\|Ax\|_{\infty}}$. Hope those can help you, good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see how this helps find an upper bound on $x$.